# ApplicationContext loading failure when using junit

Tags: junit, applicationcontext

Newcomer to spring here, so i am trying to test if the persistence of certain element in my database is perfectly done using. those elements exist in a excel file. I have tried this so far. and I keep having the same application context loading failure problem

```
`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@ContextConfiguration(
        {   "/applicationContext1.xml",
            "file:C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml",
            "file:C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml",
        }
        )
public class TestCase {

    @Autowired
    PerimetreComposantService perimetreComposantService; 

    @Test
    public void testSavePerimetreComposant() throws IOException {

        try {
            String content = readFile("C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/test.txt");
            String[] parts=content.split("@@@@");
            long id =Long.parseLong(parts[1]);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/aa.xlsx"));
            ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<Article> articles =new ArrayList();
            Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
            Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(9);
            Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                if (nextRow.getRowNum() == 0 || nextRow.getRowNum() == 1) {
                    /*
                     *   Do Nothing
                     */
                }
                else {
                    Cell cell;
                    /* For each row, iterate through each columns */
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                        /*
                         * Get the cell content including the blank cells
                         */
                        cell = nextRow.getCell(i, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        values.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        values.add(Integer.toString((int) cell
                                .getNumericCellValue()));
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        values.add(Boolean.toString((boolean) cell
                                .getBooleanCellValue()));
                        break;
                    /*
                     * When it's a blank cell, fill it with empty string
                     */
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                        values.add("");
                        break;
                    default:
                        values.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                }
                    try{
                        System.out.println("toto");
                        articles = perimetreComposantService.findArticlesBy(values.get(0), values.get(1), Double.parseDouble(values.get(2)), Integer.parseInt(values.get(3)), values.get(4), id);

                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                assertFalse(!articles.isEmpty());
                }
            }
            }
             catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }`
```

failure details:

> 2017-12-08 11:42:30 [INFO ]
>   (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:loadBeanDefinitions:315) => Loading XML
>   bean definitions from URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]
>   2017-12-08 11:42:31 [INFO ]
>   (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:loadBeanDefinitions:315) => Loading XML
>   bean definitions from URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/test-classes/applicationContext1.xml]
>   2017-12-08 11:42:31 [INFO ]
>   (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:registerBeanDefinition:665) =>
>   Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource': replacing [Generic
>   bean: class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=close;
>   defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]]
>   with [Generic bean: class [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource];
>   scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=close; defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/test-classes/applicationContext1.xml]]
>   2017-12-08 11:42:31 [INFO ]
>   (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:registerBeanDefinition:665) =>
>   Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager': replacing
>   [Generic bean: class
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]]
>   with [Generic bean: class
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/test-classes/applicationContext1.xml]]
>   2017-12-08 11:42:31 [INFO ]
>   (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:registerBeanDefinition:665) =>
>   Overriding bean definition for bean 'viewResolver': replacing [Generic
>   bean: class
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]]
>   with [Generic bean: class
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver]; scope=;
>   abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null;
>   factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null;
>   defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/test-classes/applicationContext1.xml]]
>   2017-12-08 11:42:31 [INFO ]
>   (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:registerBeanDefinition:665) =>
>   Overriding bean definition for bean 'entityManagerFactory': replacing
>   [Generic bean: class
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean];
>   scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]]
>   with [Generic bean: class
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean];
>   scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/test-classes/applicationContext1.xml]]
>   2017-12-08 11:42:31 [INFO ]
>   (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:loadBeanDefinitions:315) => Loading XML
>   bean definitions from URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml]
>   2017-12-08 11:42:31 [ERROR]
>   (TestContextManager.java:prepareTestInstance:314) => Caught exception
>   while allowing TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@5c8c05]
>   to prepare test instance
>   [com.zodiac.apcit.business.test.TestCase2@1ecade2]
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from URL
>   [file:/C:/Users/Mohammed.yasserdahbi/Desktop/Workspace/APCITA380/target/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-jpa.xml];
>   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException:
>   Invalid NamespaceHandler class
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler]
>   for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]:
>   problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:233)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
>     ... 25 more Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException:
>   Invalid NamespaceHandler class
>   [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler]
>   for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]:
>   problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception
>   is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1433)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1428)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
>     ... 38 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/NamespaceHandlerSupport     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClassOrNull(ClassLoader.java:1061)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:410)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)     at
>   org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.resolve(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:124)
>     ... 45 more

can anybody tell what is the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure nothing is missing from the stacktrace? Also, where is your applicationContext1.xml file located?

Comment: this is not the whole stacktrace. the applicationContext1.xml is in the same package with the testcase.java

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: I eddited the file

Comment: What Spring dependencies do you have?